# Exception related to async Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi

I wrote my sqlalchemy models, so i needed to retrieve related objects when getting parent.

**User model**

```
class User(AbstractBaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = Column(String, unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    hashed_password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    tests = relationship("Test", backref=backref("holder", lazy="subquery"))
    sessions = relationship("Session")
```

**Test model**

```
class Test(AbstractBaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "tests"

    title = Column(String(256))
    holder_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))
    published = Column(Boolean)
    questions = relationship("Question")
    sessions = relationship("Session")
```

So when i am trying to retreive holder object i am getting an **sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError:**

```
Parent instance <Test at 0x7f5e391522c0> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'holder' cannot proceed (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/bhk3)
```

it raises after i am using this code:

```
async def create(self, obj):
    await self._before_create()

    self._database_session.add(obj)
    await self._database_session.commit()
    await self._after_create()
```

I tried all types of lazyloading, and tried to add separate holder attr with relationship in tests but it did not help. If someone knows how to get related objects in async sqlalchemy please let me know as soon as possible.

So it is debugger screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/_modules/examples/asyncio/async_orm.html)?

Comment: Yes i did. But the case that used there requires options in select method. In my case i need to use object after add and commit methods so there is no loading options in them

Comment: What are the implementation of `_before_create`? Do you attempt to use the relationship there?  What is the implementation of these methods? Exactly where does your error happen and which line triggers it?

Comment: ```_before_create``` and ```_after_create``` are just empty functions, so anything does not happening there. First i am getting Test model object that i created from data validated by pydantic
```test_object = Test(holder_id=test.holder_id, published=test.published)```, than adding it with session. So after addding the object refreshes and when i am trying to retrieve obj.holder afrter commit. I am getting error that holder can not be proceed. I want to note that before making add and commit of session my object does not have holder at all.
PS. I will pin the image of debugger